# Symfony - Multiple form constraints on one entity property field

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints, entity

Let's say that I have a `Human` entity with a `$surname` property, and I have two form types, one for creating the entity and one for searching in entities.
When I put the annotation `Assert/NotBlank()` on the surname property, it is used for the  search form too.

Is there any way how to specify which constraint annotation should a specific form use and which not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Annotations you can also assign a **Validation Group** to the entity constraint like the example below (using annotations):

```
/**
* @Assert/NotBlank(
*     groups={"search_form"} <--- VALIDATION GROUP
* )
*/
protected $surname;
```

Depending by your needs you can add one or more validation groups to use a specific assert in different forms/contexts like: `groups={"registration", "edit", "search"}`

Then you can read the docs (*links are for the latest version*) to see:

- [How to define the validation group in your forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html)
- [How to define the validation group to validate an object directly (without using the form component)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the constraint from the class and set it in the form builders, which would allow you to have different constraints for the same field:

```
class CreateHumanType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'surname',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'label' => "surname",
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank(
                            [
                                'message' => "The surname is required",
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
                ]
            );
    }
    //[...]
}

class SearchHumanType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'surname',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'label' => "surname",
                    'required' => "false",
                ]
            );
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep the constraint in the class and set the field as not mapped for the search:

```
class SearchHumanType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'surname',
                TextType::class,
                [
                    'label' => "surname",
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
    }
    //[...]
}
```

You'd then have to handle it manually in the controller.